# All Azure Continuous Builds failed because 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensions.Intercept_x64.dll' is locked

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment, azure-application-insights

I setup continuous *Azure Websites* deployment over old *Full Azure Portal*. Each build failed because of error:

> Exception Message: Web Deploy cannot modify the file
>   'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensions.Intercept_x64.dll' on the
>   destination because it is locked by an external process.  In order to
>   allow the publish operation to succeed, you may need to either restart
>   your application to release the lock, or use the AppOffline rule
>   handler for .Net applications on your next publish attempt.

I'm able to run builds successfully when I stops the websites, but this have nothing to do with continuous integration. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it was fixed in 0.13 AI SDK. Please try to use the latest version.

Comment: Hi Anastasia! I wasn't aware of *Application Insight's* prerelease updates as they aren't show in NuGet packet manager, until explicit wanted. Thank you to make me attentive of this. However even If I  updated the solution to the latest Application Insight packages I still getting the same error.

Comment: Ok after I updated the *NuGet* packages and deployed than once manually (with the new *AI SDK* assemblies) I'm now able to deploy using  automated builds.

Answer (score 0):

It is because ApplicationInsights is monitoring your performance and it is in use by IIS as long as your application is running, hence locked.

You have two options:
Take your site offline if you need to update this resource.
Or don't update this resource if it didn't change.

EDIT:
3rd option:
You could try if the AppOffline flag can help you, but my guess is no:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/30/web-publishing-updates-for-app-offline-and-usechecksum.aspx

Comment: *AppOffline* flag didn't help me, i will check if the new SDK fixed it as @anastasia-baranchenkova proposed by her answer